# Python - Read Google Ads Keyword Planning .csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-ads-api

I am having some issues reading a file I downloaded from Google Ads Keyword Planner Tool. If I download any file from this tool (not the API but the GUI), I get a basic tab delimited CSV file like the following (when opened in notepad).

```
Keyword Stats 2019-03-01 at 14_08_25
"February 1, 2018 - January 31, 2019"
Keyword Currency    Avg. monthly searches   Min search volume   Max search volume   Competition Competition (indexed value) Top of page bid (low range) Top of page bid (high range)    Ad impression share Organic impression share    Organic average position    In account? In plan?    Searches: Feb 2018  Searches: Mar 2018  Searches: Apr 2018  Searches: May 2018  Searches: Jun 2018  Searches: Jul 2018  Searches: Aug 2018  Searches: Sep 2018  Searches: Oct 2018  Searches: Nov 2018  Searches: Dec 2018  Searches: Jan 2019
Women Fashion Plus Sizes    USD N/A 0   10  Unknown                                                                             
plus size women USD N/A "10,000"    "100,000"   High    100 0.88    2.51                                                                    
Large Fashionable Clothing  USD N/A 0   10  Unknown                                                                             
plus size clothing  USD N/A "100,000"   "1,000,000" High    100 1.02    2.79                                                                    
plus size dresses   USD N/A "100,000"   "1,000,000" High    100 0.67    1.79
```

This file also opens just fine with excel.

However, if I read the file in with Pandas using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = 10, header = 0, sep = '\t')
```

a dataframe is created that is entirely empty (all nan and unnamed headers), but with the correct number of rows and 26 columns.

If I simply open and read the file, I get a whole bunch of really odd (lots of x00) looking unicode that doesn't seem to equate to anything when read as such.

```
open(file).readlines()

    >>>  '\x00p\x00l\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00s\x00i\x00z\x00e\x00 \x00o\x00u\x00t\x00f\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00i\x00d\x00e\x00a\x00s\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00r\x00 \x00s\x00u\x00m\x00m\x00e\x00r\x00\t\x00U\x00S\x00D\x00\t\x00N\x00/\x00A\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x00\t\x00"\x001\x00,\x000\x000\x000\x00"\x00\t\x00H\x00i\x00g\x00h\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x00\t\x000\x00.\x005\x008\x00\t\x005\x00.\x006\x002\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\n',
 "\x00w\x00o\x00m\x00e\x00n\x00'\x00s\x00 \x00p\x00l\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00s\x00i\x00z\x00e\x00 \x00b\x00o\x00u\x00t\x00i\x00q\x00u\x00e\x00 \x00c\x00l\x00o\x00t\x00h\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00o\x00n\x00l\x00i\x00n\x00e\x00\t\x00U\x00S\x00D\x00\t\x00N\x00/\x00A\x00\t\x001\x000\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x00\t\x00H\x00i\x00g\x00h\x00\t\x009\x007\x00\t\x000\x00.\x005\x001\x00\t\x008\x00.\x009\x003\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\n",
'\x00w\x00o\x00m\x00e\x00n\x00s\x00 \x00p\x00l\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00s\x00i\x00z\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00t\x00o\x00r\x00e\x00\t\x00U\x00S\x00D\x00\t\x00N\x00/\x00A\x00\t\x001\x000\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x00\t\x00H\x00i\x00g\x00h\x00\t\x009\x007\x00\t\x000\x00.\x006\x002\x00\t\x001\x00.\x005\x005\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\n',
 '\x00b\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00 \x00p\x00l\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00s\x00i\x00z\x00e\x00 \x00b\x00r\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00s\x00\t\x00U\x00S\x00D\x00\t\x00N\x00/\x00A\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x00\t\x00"\x001\x00,\x000\x000\x000\x00"\x00\t\x00L\x00o\x00w\x00\t\x002\x003\x00\t\x001\x00.\x002\x003\x00\t\x007\x00.\x000\x005\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\n',
 '\x00g\x00r\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00p\x00l\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00s\x00i\x00z\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00r\x00e\x00s\x00s\x00e\x00s\x00\t\x00U\x00S\x00D\x00\t\x00N\x00/\x00A\x00\t\x001\x000\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x00\t\x00H\x00i\x00g\x00h\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\n',
 '\x00l\x00o\x00o\x00k\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00r\x00 \x00p\x00l\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00s\x00i\x00z\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00r\x00e\x00s\x00s\x00e\x00s\x00\t\x00U\x00S\x00D\x00\t\x00N\x00/\x00A\x00\t\x001\x000\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x00\t\x00H\x00i\x00g\x00h\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x00\t\x000\x00.\x005\x009\x00\t\x001\x00.\x008\x001\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\n',
 '\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00r\x00i\x00c\x00a\x00n\x00 \x00p\x00l\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00s\x00i\x00z\x00e\x00 \x00c\x00l\x00o\x00t\x00h\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00o\x00n\x00l\x00i\x00n\x00e\x00\t\x00U\x00S\x00D\x00\t\x00N\x00/\x00A\x00\t\x001\x000\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x00\t\x00U\x00n\x00k\x00n\x00o\x00w\x00n\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\n',
 ...]
```

I have tried a number of different encodings to no avail.

Ideas?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downloaded CSV file is encoded in big-endian UTF-16. I think Adwords does this to ensure compatibility with Microsoft Excel.

```python
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = 10, header = 0, sep = '\t', encoding='utf_16_be')
```

should give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

What worked me:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    "Keyword Stats file name.csv", encoding='utf_16', sep='\t', skiprows=2
)
```